# 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement', I am getting this error but i can't fix it help pls

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

``your text`const authForm = useRef();
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

```
e.preventDefault();

//formData
let form = new FormData(authForm.current);
console.log(form)
```

}

This is the code of the form just to show you i did add the ref for authForm

```
            <form ref={authForm} className="w-[80%] max-w-[400px]">....</form>
```

I did try adding an id on the form and using the document.getElementbyID it still didnt work so help me pls.
I am not fully aware about the reason behind the error still so it would be appreciated if anyone can explain it as well.`

Comment: In a submit handler, `e.target` should refer to the form, so try `new FormData(e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

i made a single-input form, assigned a useRef to it, and logged a new FormData object using the ref's "current" property, almost exactly like you did.  it worked for me!

i would recommend examining the state of your "authForm" variable right before you attempt to create your FormData object.  is the "current" value a form element?  my guess is that somehow it has been replaced or changed before that point.  perhaps the "current" value is null if useRef isn't correctly set up.  or perhaps your "form" element is being conditionally rendered and the timing of your "handleSubmit" call is causing issues.

that's the best advice i can give without seeing the rest of your code.  but the error message is very helpful, to a degree.  whatever autoForm.current is, it's clearly not the form element as expected.  your best starting point is to see what autoForm looks like when handleSubmit is called.

James' comment is probably a valid way to get around whatever problem you're having, if your handleSubmit is being called by the form, not by a button's onClick event.